# Custom Validation Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, customvalidator

I am attempting to create an MVC ASP.NET Application with EF6 Code First. I am learning how to add Custom Validation for an attribute with other attribute constraints.

Let go straight to my example, I have a class named TODL, it has 2 attributes.

```
using System;
using Avetmiss.Controllers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Avetmiss.Models
{
    public class TODL //Training organisation delivery location (NAT00020)
    {
        [StringLength(4, ErrorMessage = "postcode cannot be longer than 4 characters.")]
        [Required]
        public string postcode { get; set; }

        [CustomValidation(typeof(CustomValidationManger),"country_id_validation")]
        [Required]
        public string country_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now I would like to use Custom Validation on country_id that:

country_id must not be "1100", if postcode is "1".

Here is my Custom Validation, but it won't work.

```
using Avetmiss.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Avetmiss.Controllers
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class CustomValidationManger : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public static ValidationResult country_id_validation(string country_id_value, TODL todl)//for TODL
        {
            if (todl.postcode.Equals("1") && country_id_value.Equals("1100"))
                return new ValidationResult("country_id must not be 1100");
            else
                return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding how to inherit from `ValidationAttribute` - you need to override the the `IsValid()` method(s) - `protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) { your code here }`

Comment: You might also want to read [The complete guide to validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) which shows you how to create a conditional attribute that gives you both server and client side validation

Comment: And also you need to choose proper **Title** for your question. This isn't about EF6.